# Why does this C++ expression evaluate as False?

Tags: visual-c++

Why is this expression evaluated as False:

‘ A ‘  >  ‘ B ‘

From my understanding, according to the ASCII table, the value of uppercase A is 65 and B is 66.

Thank you.

Comment: And why should `65 > 66` be `true`?

Comment: 65 is less than 66.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

65 is less than 66.

Thats the reason.

Comment: I’m embarrassed. Thanks.